# Rcpp implementation of fast nonnegative least squares?

Tags: r, constraints, rcpp, least-squares

I was on the lookout of a fast implementation in R of the fast (active set based) nonnegative least squares algorithm of
[Bro, R., & de Jong, S. (1997) A fast non-negativity-constrained least squares algorithm. Journal of Chemometrics, 11, 393-401.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiNiujktdzkAhUEL1AKHcTECfgQFjABegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxrm.phys.northwestern.edu%2Fresearch%2Fpdf_papers%2F1997%2Fbro_chemometrics_1997.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3eB3Es6Le_LdFO2wVu_Qep)
In the [multiway package I found this pure R implementation](https://github.com/cran/multiway/blob/master/R/fnnls.R):

```
fnnls <- 
  function(XtX,Xty,ntol=NULL){     
    ### initialize variables
    pts <- length(Xty)
    if(is.null(ntol)){
      ntol <- 10*(.Machine$double.eps)*max(colSums(abs(XtX)))*pts
    }
    pvec <- matrix(0,1,pts)
    Zvec <- matrix(1:pts,pts,1)
    beta <- zvec <- t(pvec)
    zz <- Zvec
    wvec <- Xty - XtX%*%beta
    
    ### iterative procedure
    iter <- 0    
    itmax <- 30*pts
    
    # outer loop
    while(any(Zvec>0) && any(wvec[zz]>ntol)) {
      
      tt <- zz[which.max(wvec[zz])]
      pvec[1,tt] <- tt
      Zvec[tt] <- 0
      pp <- which(pvec>0)
      zz <- which(Zvec>0)
      nzz <- length(zz)
      zvec[pp] <- smpower(XtX[pp,pp],-1)%*%Xty[pp]
      zvec[zz] <- matrix(0,nzz,1)
      
      # inner loop
      while(any(zvec[pp]<=ntol) &&  iter<itmax) {
        
        iter <- iter + 1
        qq <- which((zvec<=ntol) & t(pvec>0))
        alpha <- min(beta[qq]/(beta[qq]-zvec[qq]))
        beta <- beta + alpha*(zvec-beta)
        indx <- which((abs(beta)<ntol) & t(pvec!=0))
        Zvec[indx] <- t(indx)
        pvec[indx] <- matrix(0,1,length(indx))
        pp <- which(pvec>0)
        zz <- which(Zvec>0)
        nzz <- length(zz)
        if(length(pp)>0){
          zvec[pp] <- smpower(XtX[pp,pp],-1)%*%Xty[pp]
        }
        zvec[zz] <- matrix(0,nzz,1)      
        
      } # end inner loop
      
      beta <- zvec
      wvec <- Xty - XtX%*%beta
      
    } # end outer loop
    
    beta
    
  }
```

but in my tests it is way slower than the [plain `nnls` function in the `nnls` package](https://rdrr.io/cran/nnls/man/nnls.html) (coded in fortran), even though algorithmically `fnnls` should be faster. I was wondering if anyone would happen to have an `Rcpp` port of `fnnls` available, ideally using armadillo classes and allowing `X` to be sparse and maybe also supporting Y to have multiple columns? Or some other nnls implementation that works with sparse covariate matrices and multiple right hand sides?

Comment: Should be doable via Armadillo in RcppArmadillo (and also via Eigen in RcppEigen, but I use the former more).  StackOverflow does not look kindly upon these kinds of questions so this may get closed.  The rcpp-devel list is less stringent ;-)

Comment: Yes I noticed there was several votes to close the question - people seem quite strict out here with their rules, but this seemed like a fair question to me... :-) Plus I am sure useful to a lot of people if somebody would come up with a nice answer. I was surprised in fact I couldn't even easily find a nice C or C++ nnls port - most of the ones I could find just used f2c to translate the original fortran code to C, but that doesn't really result in very readable code....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT Jan 2022:**  Use the `nnls` function in the RcppML R package on CRAN. This is an even faster Eigen-based implementation of the function given below, followed up by a coordinate descent least squares refinement.

---

I've spent almost a week on this problem, for research purposes.

I've also spent almost two days trying to parse through the `multiway::fnnls` implementation, and will refrain from exercising choice words on R etiquette, interpretability, and memory usage.

I fail to understand why the authors of `multiway::fnnls` think their implementation should be fast at all. The R-only implementation seems useless given the fortran Lawson/Hanson implementation.

Here's an RcppArmadillo function I wrote (Fast Approximate Solution Trajectory) NNLS which replicates `multiway::fnnls` for well-conditioned systems:

```
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace arma;
typedef unsigned int uint;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec fastnnls(mat a, vec b) {

  // initial x is the unbounded least squares solution
  vec x = arma::solve(a, b, arma::solve_opts::likely_sympd + arma::solve_opts::fast);
  
  while (any(x < 0)) {

    // define the feasible set as all values greater than 0
    arma::uvec nz = find(x > 0);
    
    // reset x
    x.zeros();
    
    // solve the least squares solution for values in the feasible set
    x.elem(nz) = solve(a.submat(nz, nz), b.elem(nz), arma::solve_opts::likely_sympd + arma::solve_opts::fast);
  }
  return x;
}
```

This approach is essentially the first half of TNT-NN, but without the "heuristics" at each iteration trying to add or remove elements from the feasible set.

To move this approach beyond a simple approximation, we can add sequential coordinate descent which receives the `FAST` solution above as initialization. In general, for most small well-conditioned problems, 99% of the time, `FAST` gives the exact solution.

A unique property of the above implementation is that it cannot give false positives, but sometimes (in large or ill-conditioned systems) gives false negatives. Thus, may be slightly sparser than the actual solution. Note that loss is generally within 1% between FAST and the exact solution, so if you're not after the absolute exact solution this is your best bet.

The above algorithm also operates much faster than the Lawson/Hanson nnls solver. Here's a microbenchmark I just copied over from a 50-coefficient system, replicated 10000 times:

```
Unit: microseconds
               expr   min    lq      mean median    uq     max neval
           fastnnls  53.9  56.2  59.32761   58.0  59.5   359.7 10000
 lawson/hanson nnls 112.9 116.7 125.96169  118.6 129.5 11032.4 10000
```

Of course, performance varies based on density and negativity. My algorithm tends to get faster with increasing sparsity, and faster with fewer positive solutions, compared to other algorithms.

I have tried and failed to simplify the multiway::fnnls code and run it into Armadillo.

I am working to implement this method as an Rcpp package and will post up when it makes it to a stable Github release.

p.s.: it is possible to make this faster using Eigen. The armadillo solver uses Cholesky decomposition and direct substitution. Eigen's Cholesky solver is faster because it does more operations in-place.

Comment: Many thanks for this, that's great! I also found out that the osqp package offers another possibility to solve nonnegative least squares problems with a sparse covariate matrix, if you first reformulate the problem as a quadratic programming problem. Haven't checked the performance yet compared to the method above though...

Comment: @TomWenseleers I have an extensive R package and baby-glam manuscript in the works. I'll post here when it hits biorxiv. Fastest NNLS around (the above method is a subroutine), with support for L1, L2, angular, and "convex"/near-exact/exact L0 regularization.

Comment: Ha sounds very interesting! For L0 penalized / best subset one can use iterative adaptive ridge regression, with adaptive penalty weights 1/(the previously fitted coefficient+eps)^2, as in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X17305067 and https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0148620 and if you replace the standard least squares in the IRLS procedure used to fit GLMs with an nnls, http://bwlewis.github.io/GLM/, you can also use it to do L0 penalized GLMs with nonnegativity constraints. Was working on package to do that.

Comment: @TomWenseleers wow, I hadn't seen either paper! At first glance it looks like both methods will give meaningful solutions, but not exact L0 solutions. I'd be really curious to see what you come up with in your package! I've written an exact L0 which is tractable up to 15 variables, and use this to benchmark my near-exact algorithm, which is feasible up to 500 or so variables and considers permutations. My convex algorithm is feasible to the thousands, but does not consider permuting the feasible set. I strongly suspect an L2-based approach like the above is better if speed is a concern.

Comment: Yes, it's not exact, but in my tests this method produced superior solutions to either the L0learn package or https://github.com/ryantibs/best-subset and much faster too. For problems with sparse covariate matrices it worked well for problems with 10s of 1000s of variables or more, if I used Eigen's LeastSquaresConjugateGradient solver & clipping to achieve nonnegativity constraints. Because it uses L2 regularisation it also works well for high dimensional problems. Inference I was doing via bootstrapping, but that's slow unfortunately...

Comment: Random comment in case anyone runs into a similar situation as me. This method was slower than the standard nnls and I was having trouble pinning down why. The culprit was crossprod! I had a very large (but sparse!) matrix, and crossprod took a long time to run. I guess some aspect of the nnls function in the nnls package optimizes this crossprod operation a bit, or somehow avoids it... The solution was to use the Matrix package, convert my matrix to a sparse matrix via Matrix(x, sparse = TRUE), then perform Matrix::crossprod(x, x). Then convert back to a standard matrix for RcppML::nnls().

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I asked OpenAI's code-davinci-002 https://beta.openai.com/playground?model=code-davinci-002 to translate the `fnnls` pure R code in the `multiway` package to `Rcpp` and this is what it comes up with - likely in no way optimal though, but perhaps a start for anyone interested in this...

```
/* Convert the following R code below to calculate a fast nonnegative least squares fit to Rcpp and use RcppArmadillo classes. */

fnnls <- 
  function(XtX,Xty,ntol=NULL){
    # Fast Non-Negative Least Squares algorithm based on 
    #   Bro, R., & de Jong, S. (1997) A fast non-negativity-constrained 
    #   least squares algorithm. Journal of Chemometrics, 11, 393-401.
    # Nathaniel E. Helwig (helwig@umn.edu)
    # last updated: April 9, 2015
    
    ### initialize variables
    pts <- length(Xty)
    if(is.null(ntol)){
      ntol <- 10*(.Machine$double.eps)*max(colSums(abs(XtX)))*pts
    }
    pvec <- matrix(0,1,pts)
    Zvec <- matrix(1:pts,pts,1)
    beta <- zvec <- t(pvec)
    zz <- Zvec
    wvec <- Xty - XtX%*%beta
    
    ### iterative procedure
    iter <- 0    
    itmax <- 30*pts
    
    # outer loop
    while(any(Zvec>0) && any(wvec[zz]>ntol)) {
      
      tt <- zz[which.max(wvec[zz])]
      pvec[1,tt] <- tt
      Zvec[tt] <- 0
      pp <- which(pvec>0)
      zz <- which(Zvec>0)
      nzz <- length(zz)
      zvec[pp] <- smpower(XtX[pp,pp],-1)%*%Xty[pp]
      zvec[zz] <- matrix(0,nzz,1)
      
      # inner loop
      while(any(zvec[pp]<=ntol) &&  iter<itmax) {
        
        iter <- iter + 1
        qq <- which((zvec<=ntol) & t(pvec>0))
        alpha <- min(beta[qq]/(beta[qq]-zvec[qq]))
        beta <- beta + alpha*(zvec-beta)
        indx <- which((abs(beta)<ntol) & t(pvec!=0))
        Zvec[indx] <- t(indx)
        pvec[indx] <- matrix(0,1,length(indx))
        pp <- which(pvec>0)
        zz <- which(Zvec>0)
        nzz <- length(zz)
        if(length(pp)>0){
          zvec[pp] <- smpower(XtX[pp,pp],-1)%*%Xty[pp]
        }
        zvec[zz] <- matrix(0,nzz,1)      
        
      } # end inner loop
      
      beta <- zvec
      wvec <- Xty - XtX%*%beta
      
    } # end outer loop
    
    beta
    
  }
```

Answer:

```
# [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec fnnls(const arma::mat& XtX, const arma::vec& Xty, double ntol = NULL){
  
  // initialize variables
  int pts = Xty.n_elem;
  if (ntol == NULL){
    ntol = 10*(std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())*arma::max(arma::sum(arma::abs(XtX),1))*pts;
  }
  arma::mat pvec = arma::zeros<arma::mat>(1,pts);
  arma::vec Zvec = arma::regspace<arma::vec>(1,pts);
  arma::vec beta = arma::zeros<arma::vec>(pts);
  arma::vec zvec = pvec.t();
  arma::uvec zz = find(Zvec>0);
  arma::vec wvec = Xty - XtX*beta;

  // iterative procedure
  int iter = 0;    
  int itmax = 30*pts;

  // outer loop
  while((any(Zvec>0)) && (any(wvec(zz)>ntol))){

    int tt = zz[wvec.elem(zz).index_max()];
    pvec.col(tt) += tt;
    Zvec[tt] = 0;
    arma::uvec pp = find(pvec>0);
    zz = find(Zvec>0);
    int nzz = zz.n_elem;

    zvec.elem(pp) = solve(XtX.submat(pp,pp),Xty.elem(pp));

    zvec.elem(zz).zeros();

    // inner loop
    while((any(zvec.elem(pp)<=ntol)) && (iter<itmax)){

      iter++;

      arma::uvec qq = find((zvec<=ntol) && (pvec>0));

      double alpha = min((beta.elem(qq)/((beta.elem(qq)-zvec.elem(qq)))));

      beta += alpha*((zvec-beta));

      arma::uword indx;

      for (arma::uword i=0; i < beta.n_elem; i++){

        if ((abs(beta[i]) < ntol) && (pvec[i] != 0)){

          indx = i;

          Zvec[indx] += indx;

          pvec[indx] += 0;

        }

      }

      pp = find(pvec>0);

      zz = find(Zvec>0);

      nzz = zz.n_elem;

      if (pp.n_elem > 0){

        zvec.elem(pp) = solve(XtX.submat(pp,pp),Xty.elem(pp));

      }      

      zvec.elem(zz).zeros();      

    } // end inner loop    

    beta = zvec;    

    wvec -= XtX*beta;    

  } // end outer loop  

  return beta;  
}
```